# Uploading to a domain with WordPress extension

Tags: php, wordpress, web, web-hosting

Hey guys am about to host a website and I think I may have a looming issue at hand I have been editing a website on WordPress online mywebsite.com/wp-login.php but have not publish it (still a blank domain) now few weeks after I decided to start the project all over again using MVC php now I want to know if I can still upload my site to mywebsite.com without having any issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move all your custom php files to a sub directory and put the wordpress site's files on the root directory. That will be safe I guess.

Comment: I dnt want to make use of the WordPress files again I just want the new website ,I want to know if I won't have issue

Comment: If you donot want to use the wordpress. Then delete wordpress files/folders and only put your custom php files there.